# How to select points as geometry in QGIS when both multipolygons and points are stated within the wfs-server?

Tags: qgis, wfs, filter

I'm trying to show data from the following server in QGIS: http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&

I made a filter on the data I would like to appear in my map. This is how I stated the wfs-url in QGIS:

```
http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?VERSION=1.0.0&cql_filter=postcode LIKE '6828%'
```

The following link is an example on how the data appears in xml-format (different filter):

```
http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=bagviewer:verblijfsobject&count=10&srsname=EPSG:28992&bbox=189869.57826037705,444557.7565065846,190175.32637351775,444863.5046197253
```

In the last link it show two kinds of geometry, one is called geometrie (points) and the other pandgeomotrie (multipolygon). The geometry appears in polygons on the map, though I would like the points to appear on the map.

Is there a way of doing this?